# .net c# Winforms .exe wont start on any other machine

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

Ive developed a winforms application on my local machine using .net 4.0 and it runs fine. I have all dotnet versions installed.

When I copied the .exe and all of its references (the complete bin\debug and bin\release) to another machine it simply does not run. On one of my VMS it fires up visual studio express and asks if I want to connect a debgger. On other machines it just doesnt do anything.

But I can work out what on earth is going on.

I have referenced soem xceed dlls that are installed in GAC but not on the target machines GAC could this be the problem?

How do I tell what the hell is going on?

Pete

Comment: generally it's not a spectacular idea to simply copy and paste files in an attempt to "install" an application on another machine. 'tis a much better idea to create a Setup project in order to make an installer for your application.

Comment: Try to drop your non GAC referenced dlls in same folder as the exe and try again. Obviously there will be a problem if can't find the required dlls.

Comment: Check your event log, maybe you can find out which dll is missing.

Comment: What does "it just doesn't do anything" mean?  Do you get an error message at all?  Are you running it by double-clicking on the application in Windows Explorer (or a shortcut), or are you running from the command line?  If you run from the command line, you're more likely to get some helpful information like an exception displayed in the console window when the program shuts down.

Comment: @brian driscoll who said I was trying to install it? :-) Why write an installer if the app doesnt work yet? thanks for the reply im just a bit confused by it.

Comment: @Pete2k creating a proper installer will ensure that all of your application's dependencies are resolved on the target machine, which is what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the xceed dlls (and every other referenced dlls) must exist on the target machine -- either included in the application directory or the GAC.

You may try specifying "Copy Local = true" to the suspect references, and rebuilding your project, so that these dlls are specifically included with the compiled assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the other machine has a version of the .Net Framework installed? Failing that try to publish the application using the ClickOnce tool.

ClickOnce will download and instal any missing dependencies for the .Net Framework if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

if you deploy the pdb-files to the one VM with VS Express installed you should be able to connect the debugger and see the exception details. And yes, a missing assembly can (or better: will) cause that kind of behavior if the assembly is not only referenced but actually used in your application. I would generally recommend to implement some kind of error logging (either to the event logs or to a text file).